# Getting FileLoaderLoadException in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony.I am trying to learn File upload in Symfony.I am getting below error:

**(3/3) FileLoaderLoadException
The file "D:\wamp\www\symfony_project\app/config\services.yml" does not contain valid YAML in D:\wamp\www\symfony_project\app/config\services.yml (which is being imported from "D:\wamp\www\symfony_project\app/config\config.yml").**

config.yml

```
parameters:
brochures_directory: '%kernel.symfony_project%/../web/uploads/brochures'
```

services.yml

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more services, or override services that need manual wiring
    # AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
    #     arguments:
    #         $someArgument: 'some_value'
    admin.category:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Category, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Category }
        public: true

    admin.blog_post:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\BlogPostAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Blog post }
        public: true

     AppBundle\Service\FileUploader:
        arguments:
            targetDir: '%brochures_directory%'
```

FileUploader.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class FileUploader
{
    private $targetDir;

    public function __construct($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->getTargetDir(), $fileName);

        return $fileName;
    }

    public function getTargetDir()
    {
        return $this->targetDir;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Can you show your `FileUploader` class?

Comment: You have to indent the brochures_directory parameter with four spaces. But in any case, as said, better if you post the whole file.

Comment: @Carlos and Imanali I posted It

Comment: @Swati, belive it or not, it was not visible when I posted previous answer. Correct the indentation in your config.yml file.

Comment: @Carlos can you plz tell me with an example.?

Comment: @swati Done as an asnwer

Comment: I posted your configuration. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `services.yml` is not valid YAML. Remove `$` sign before `targetDir` in line:

```
        $targetDir: '%brochures_directory%'
```

So it will be:

```
AppBundle\Service\FileUploader:
    arguments:
        targetDir: '%brochures_directory%'
```

I guess that this is your issue, but I cannot be sure as I don't know how looks the whole content of this file.

Comment: So the issue is in other place than the sample that you've provided. Paste whole `services.yml` file taking care of whitespaces as they are important in YAML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

your services.yml does not contain valid YAML (Error message can't be more clear ;) )

Try this kind of code :

```
/***/
admin.blog_post:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\BlogPostAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost, ~]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Blog post }
    public: true

admin.file_uploader:
    class: AppBundle\Service\FileUploader
    arguments: [~, '%brochures_directory%', ~]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
parameters:
brochures_directory: '%kernel.symfony_project%/../web/uploads/brochures'
```

To

```
parameters:
    brochures_directory: '%kernel.symfony_project%/../web/uploads/brochures'
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work now:

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags:
          - { name: "controller.service_arguments" }

    # add more services, or override services that need manual wiring
    # AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
    #     arguments:
    #         $someArgument: 'some_value'
    admin.category:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Category, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Category }
        public: true

    admin.blog_post:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\BlogPostAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Blog post }
        public: true

    AppBundle\Service\FileUploader:
        arguments:
            targetDir: '%brochures_directory%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have space in front of `AppBundle\Service\FileUploader`:

```
→ ﹍AppBundle\Service\FileUploader:
    arguments:
        targetDir: '%brochures_directory%'
```

Hint: In future use Yaml linter:

```
bin/console lint:yaml app/config/services.yml
```

[image: Symfony YAML linter]